# Nodejs running daily task

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to run a nodejs function daily. I have pretty much decided to use [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) rather than a cron job.

The question is: Without a db what is the best way to ensure that I don't somehow run the function more than once? My though was to keep a log of each time I send out and double check by reading the log before sending and checking that I haven't sent yet today. I know that node-schedule shouldn't run more often than I tell it but someone might restart the script or something stupid, I want to be extra safe.

Note: I cannot setup a db due to limited access to the server.

Comment: Just write out a simple piece of JSON to a file each time you run it that records the last time you ran it.  Upon server startup, read in that JSON and check when it was last run.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah I was thinking about something like that or just checking my log file (I always log requests and actions anyways). Was just wondering whether I was thinking about this wrong somehow :)

Comment: Out of curiosity: why not use cron?

Comment: @mscdex no particular reason I might still do that. It isn't really the issue that I'm trying to solve though. One reason would be if I try to run this parallel to a web server if that's possible somehow

Answer (score 2):

One common solution is to create a pid file somewhere. If the pid file exists, exit the process early. Otherwise create the pid file (writing `process.pid` to it) and delete it when the process exits.